# itextsharp spliting a row in multiple page (at Absolute position)

Tags: itext

I'm in a situation where I need to split a (large) row into multiple page with ITextSharp.

My main difficulty is linked to the fact I need to put the table at position (x,y), so using **WriteSelectedRows** instead of **Document.add()**.

In this case, **SplitLate** & **SplitRows** are useless.

If anyone knows how to split a row on multiple pages, you are more than welcome.

Comment: If you need so specific control over how the contents of a single table row are positioned and split, are you sure your approach to use a single table row for them is appropriate?

Comment: well, it's a good question - whatever I do 1 or many tables, a cell could be superior to the document's height, so I need to split it (cell is generated from HTML conversion). So need to find a way to split the row (or the cell) with specific height.